# Expo/React Native: EventSource does not launch in expo-dev-client

Tags: android, react-native, expo, event-sourcing

I have a problem with using EventListener. Here is the code:

```
import EventSource from 'react-native-event-source';
...

const exampleFunction = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const connectEventSource = () => {
          const eventSource = new EventSource(`${API_URL}`, {
          });

          eventSource.addEventListener('ping', function (event) {
            console.log('Received ping', event.data);
          });
}
```

The problem is that after opening the EventListener, no responses are returned. EventSource reports that it is listening, but no pings or other responses are received, even though the server is sending them. The problem occurs exclusively in the development profile application (running in expo-dev-client). In every other case - application running in Expo Go, Preview, or released through the store, everything works fine, and the responses (pings) are received and processed correctly. Testing the API through the Postman app also works correctly. The problem occurs both on expo-dev-client running on a phone and locally on an emulator on a computer.

I was reviewing the app settings on the phone, changing the internet connection, checking logs and information on the server (without errors on either side).